# how to make click on checkbox text position change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

what i am trying to do is in my below code is when i click on checked the test paragraph is show in center and when i unclick the checkbox then test paragraph is show in right using css html javascript

but in my below code its not happen.

how can we do?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">test!</p>
```

if any help its very thankful.

Comment: there is no dropdown  in your code. you mean the select HTML element ?

Comment: You are talking about positioning in drop-down we don't see. You need to create proper [mre] incuding all relevant CSS and HTML, no one can help you without it. You now do nothing but show hide, witch has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: @ikiK  i am posted in my code above what i try to make when i click on checkbox then show test paragraph in center and when i unchecked then its show right side

Comment: but right now in my above code happening is when i click the checkbox its show in center and when i unclick its hide  but what i try to make when i click on checkbox then show test paragraph in center and when i unchecked then its show right side

Comment: is there any help in this

Comment: @MisterJojo  i am posted in my code above what i try to make when i click on checkbox then show test paragraph in center and when i unchecked then its show test paragraph right side and  right now in my above code happening is when i click the checkbox its show in center and when i unclick its hide but what i try to make when i click on checkbox then show test paragraph in center and when i unchecked then its show right side

Comment: HTML paragraph element `<p>` can't be on left or right because they always use the **full** width of his page.

Comment: Have you written any CSS we could see? At the moment as you say you are just toggling display on and off. You will need some CSS to position the text where you want it which you could probably do by styling the p element. Do you want it to change size?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myChk  = document.getElementById("myCheck")
  ,   elText = document.getElementById("text")
  ;
myChk.onclick = e => 
  {
  if (myChk.checked && elText.className === 'noDisplay' )
    text.className = ''
 
  if (!myChk.checked && elText.className === '' )
    text.className = 'rightDisplay'
  }
```

```css
#text {
  width   : 200px;
  height  : 100px;
  padding : 10px 20px;
  background-color : pink;
  }
.noDisplay { 
  display : none  
  }
.rightDisplay {
  float   : right 
  }
```

```html
<label>Checkbox:
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" >
</label> 

<div id="text" class="noDisplay" >test!</div>
```